# ¿Por qué algunos miembros de aquí son arrogantes?

Tags: discusión

Soy miembro en esta comunidad y en ocasiones veo que algunos usuarios son bien criticones o arrogantes y no piensan que algunas preguntas son algo tonta para ellos porque para ellos es fácil o ya lo conocen pero no entienden que hay programadores que son nuevos y novatos y no conocen bien algunos conceptos o algún tema pero ahí van y los critican o algo parecido así obvio. Yo no rompo las reglas.

---

¿Y quién es el moderador en este sitio?

Comment: Hol Gilberto. Por favor selecciona [edit] en tu pregunta y agrega ejemplos de la arrogancia de las personas en publicaciones que hayas visto (no necesariamente deben ser publicaciones tuyas).

Comment: Disculpa por la falta de ortografía pero estoy un móvil

Comment: Gilberto, demuestras tu prudencia al no poner ejemplos nominativos, los cuales inevitablemente acabarían siendo vistos como una acusación por parte de los nombrados. Es mejor tratar este tema sin acusaciones, al menos al principio. Mejor no echar leña al fuego. El problema es real, yo también lo percibo.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. He visto actitudes prepotentes, arrogantes e impositivas como por ejemplo del señor Mendoza y alguna otra. Quizas deberian no descalificar las respuestas y preguntas de otros porque no les gustan. Quizas el que pregunto si la aprecia y en el futuro otros tambien. Yo visito este sitio para aprender y a veces lo hago enseñando (El que enseña aprende el doble). No me interesa ni puntos, ni nada. Así que no me importa las repercusiones a este comentario. La puedo usar de forma anomina o ir a cualquier otro sitio. Ojala Stack en español siga creciendo.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos Sin ejemplos (aún cuando no sean con nombre del usuario) lo que tenemos es simplemente la percepción de un usuario de algo que pudo o no ser arrogante.

Comment: @Fpme ejemplos por favor. Sin ejemplos, es como no decir nada.

Comment: @Jorgesys: Según entiendo sólo debería usarse una de las etiquetas mandatorias, en este caso discusión o soporte. Me parece bien que hayas agregado la etiqueta discusión porque la pregunta es basada en opiniones, pero considero que debió haberse quitado la de soporte pues según entiendo sólo debe usarse una de las etiquetas mandatorias en cada discusión. Por lo anterior, quitaré la de soporte.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Gilberto, me llamo la atención tu pregunta y quiero externar mi punto de vista acerca de esto, creo que esto forma parte de situaciones que varios de nosotros hemos experimentado en la vida, entiendo que en ocasiones para alguien puede ser molesto, para otros no tanto el recibir una critica, esto también dependiendo del tipo de critica la cual puede ser constructiva pero en otras ocasiones la critica tiene otra connotación muy diferente.

Como recomendación **te sugiero enfocarte en el objetivo que es obtener información que te ayude a solucionar el problema que publicas en tu pregunta.**

**Poner atención a las personas que en verdad cumplen el objetivo de ayudarte y aprender de ellos.** En cambio evitar discusiones con quien va a buscar un detalle para hacerte ver miles de detalles.

Mis sugerencias se basan en que soy alguien que en ocasiones desconozco muchas cosas, pero se que es muy importante preguntar, así sea algo muy básico, seguramente habrá quien considere risible o tonto como lo comentas, pero no te preocupes tal vez estas personas ya pasaron esta etapa que fue desgraciadamente de esta forma.

> ¿Qué es lo que siempre le has querido preguntar a una mujer o a un
>   hombre y no te atreves? ... Si te quedas con la duda, nunca lo sabrás!

**Solo recuerda que cuando tengas el conocimiento y veas que alguien pregunta algo que sea básico para ti,  trata de ayudarlo y no realices la misma conducta, mientras tanto cuando desconozcas algo no dejes de externar tus dudas para obtener el conocimiento.**

**Sigue aportando a la comunidad** preguntando (**tratando como ya lo han comentado otros compañeros de mejorar la calidad de las preguntas, agregar código de lo que hayas tratado o documentar fuentes que hayas tratado**) y respondiendo, con esto aportas a que otros nuevos usuarios que tengan dudas encuentren la respuesta a lo que tu alguna vez buscabas.

Answer (score 12):

En el asunto de la arrogancia hay que considerar varias cosas.

**SO es un sitio en que que tiene su cantidad significativa de informáticos como usuarios.**

No es un secreto que informáticos no son exactamente famoso por sus habilidades sociales o diplomáticos. Eso no significa que no lo pueden tener, pero que no necesariamente se puede esperar que los tienen. Ten paciencia.

**Arrogancia no siempre lo es.**

Cada uno tiene su propia forma de comunicarse. Algunos tienen un sentido de humor excéntrico, otros simplemente no sienten que tienen tempo para ser amable, otros más tratan ser amable, pero alguien se ganó una medalla borrándoles todo que escribieron que podría haber suavizado un poco una crítica valida. Ten paciencia.

**A nadie le pagan aquí**

La gente que se toman el tiempo para responderte a tus preguntas lo hacen gratis. Eso no es una excusa para falta de cortesía, pero al otro lado es difícil de exigir dado las circunstancias. Ten paciencia y disfruta la gente que se toman el tiempo **y** más encima te tratan amable y con paciencia.

**¿La respuesta o el comentario arrogante me ayudó?**
Yo prefiero una respuesta útil pero arrogante cualquier día sobre una respuesta que no me enseña nada pero eso con mucha empatía (Mi navegador me marca empatía como palabra desconocida/falta de ortografía - véase "informáticos").
Muchos consideran [djb](http://cr.yp.to/cv.html) arrogante por ejemplo, sin embargo **yo** sería más feliz que perro con dos colas recibiendo una respuesta arrogante de el (si logro inventar una pregunta suficientemente interesante para llamar su atención).

**SO trata implementar meritocracia**
Si sientes que faltan gente amable y cortes aquí, trata dar un mejor ejemplo, y usa tus votos para fomentar el estilo de moderación y respuestas que a ti conviene. Eso es el impacto que tienes. Pero ¡ojo!, no olvides que lo más importante aquí es el contenido de las publicaciones, menos el estilo, mientras tanto no queda ofensivo. Haces un flaco favor a todos si terminas fomentando *blabla*, solamente porque fue entregado en forma amable.

**Puedes dar un mejor ejemplo**
Si tu ves respuesta que te parecen arrogante, poco paciente y tu sientes que el OP necesita un poco más información, escribe una respuesta más explicativa. Si resulta que la gente prefieren las respuestas más amigables y menos bruscas, se va reflejar en votos y aceptación. Eso probable es la única forma como enfrentar un exceso de arrogancia, porque es dentro de la naturaleza de la arrogancia que es muy difícil de cambiar un arrogante. ;)

Ahora, si la arrogancia llega al punto que es una falta de respeto, ofensivo o humillante, debes reportarlo, independiente de quien se trata.

Comment: "Informáticos": No es un secreto que informáticos no son exactamente famoso por sus habilidades sociales o diplomáticos. hehe =)

Comment: A Juan M le pagan.

Comment: Juan M no es un "moderador" como los demás, él es el gerente de la comunidad.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos JuanM no es informático, JuanM es empleado de StackOverflow (por ende a él le pagan). Aún así, él brinda bastante apoyo a la comunidad fuera de lo que es "solo su trabajo".

Answer (score 11):

Tienes ejemplos de comentarios de lo que consideras rudos o arrogantes?

Lo adecuado es reportar ese contenido como Irrespetuoso u Ofensivo y si un usuario en particular es el que se comporta así, avisar a los moderadores.

Los moderadores son: Miquel Coll, Luiggi Mendoza y  <strike>Konamiman</strike>  (ya no lo es, es empleado de SO) y tienen un diamante ♦

En las preguntas tienes un boton de reportar. Le das a "se necesita la intervencion de un moderador" y explicas lo sucedido.

<sub>Nota: Recuerda que tambien tienes el [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) para discutir temas e incluso invocar (con @) a usuarios.</sub>

Comment: Acotación: Konamiman no es moderador, es empleado de StackOverflow

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Oh! pensaba que si, aunque no se le ve mucho el pelo xD Como aqui pone [el primer moderador](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/276/conozcan-a-nuestro-primer-moderador-konamiman) ... hahah

Comment: Lo fue, pero ya no lo es. Ser empleado de StackOverflow es una labor mayor (y por defecto tienes el diamante)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza entiendo, gracias por la info! :D

Comment: @lois6b añadiría que el uso del `chat` y la `intervención del moderador` solo deberían usarse cuando la situación es recurrente _(y tal vez, recomendado - según sea el caso - documentar esas situaciones)_. Digo esto porque en una respuesta que publiqué a otra pregunta en el Meta de Stack Overflow en Español, recibí [este comentario](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1113/se-podr%C3%ADa-a%C3%B1adir-una-opci%C3%B3n-para-cerrar-una-pregunta-por-tarea-escolar/1333#comment3515_1333) _el cual es válido, por cierto_ :)

Comment: @Mauricio quiza no me expresé bien pero era mi intencion diciendo que "si un usuario en particular es el que se comporta así" como diciendo que es uno el que reiteradamente hace comentarios asi

Answer (score 0):

En lo que respecta a quienes son los moderadores, véanse:

- [¿Quiénes son los moderadores?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators)<sup>1</sup>

  - Página que lista a los moderadores de la comunidad, identificados con un diamante luego de su nombre de usuario.
- [¿Quiénes son los moderadores del sitio y cuál es su cometido?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)

  - Artículo de ayuda
- [Una teoría de moderación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2227/65)

  - Traducción de un artículo de blog por uno de los co-fundadores de la red de Stack Exchange, en el que explica uno de los pilares del modelo de operación de los sitios de la red.

En cuanto a los motivos por los cuales algunos miembros aquí son como son, como has visto por las tres respuestas previas hay diversas opiniones. La norma de comportamiento está en [Compórtate bien](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) y es labor de todos nosotros cumplirla y hacerla cumplir.

Reporta los comentarios que te parezcan ofensivos o no constructivos para que estos sean revisados por los miembros de la comunidad con los privilegios correspondientes.

---

Notas:

1. No estoy de acuerdo con el título del primer enlace ya que como en el segundo se indica, varios de los privilegios de moderación se ganan con base en el nivel de reputación que se tiene.