# Se va ha seguir tapando este tipo de comportamientos o se tiene pensado hacer algo al respecto.

Tags: discusión

Hacia los que corresponda:

**Usuarios, Moderadores, Community Manager.**

Una de las primeras publicaciones en meta que lei despues de algun tiempo fueron estas:

[Mal Comportamiento de Usuarios](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1411/mal-comportamiento-de-usuarios-mas-experimentado-contra-novatos)

> 4 upvote
>
> Podrias poner ejemplos de mal comportamiento? de criticas?
>   No está ya respondida tu pregunta sobre "usuarios arrogantes"? –
>   lois6b

---

[¿Por qué algunos miembros de aquí son arrogantes?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1360/por-qu%C3%A9-algunos-miembros-de-aqu%C3%AD-son-arrogantes)

> 6 upvote
>
> Hol Gilberto. Por favor selecciona editar en tu pregunta y agrega
>   ejemplos de la arrogancia de las personas en publicaciones que hayas
>   visto (no necesariamente deben ser publicaciones tuyas). – Luiggi
>   Mendoza♦

.

> 2 upvote
>
> @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos Sin ejemplos (aún cuando no
>   sean con nombre del usuario) lo que tenemos es simplemente la
>   percepción de un usuario de algo que pudo o no ser arrogante. – Lamak
>   el 6 feb.

.

> @Fpme ejemplos por favor. Sin ejemplos, es como no decir nada. –
>   Luiggi Mendoza♦

---

Lo cual se que es verdad, que existe este tipo de comportamientos, **no todos actuan asi** por suerte pero los hay, y lo que mas me molesta, es como se quiere **tapar**, la existencia de los mismos, casi dejando por loco al usuario/os que lo exponen, alegando o dando a entender que son invenciones del mismo, pues yo he visto malos comportamientos antes y ahora.

Pero siempre solian ser hacia usuarios nuevos, o por preguntas muy basicas, pero, lo anterior en **ningun momento** bajo mi punto de vista, otorga el derecho a **nadie** se cual sea su posicion dentro la comunidad a comportamiento inadecuados.

Algunos, o muchos pedian pruebas y el caso, es que me acaba de suceder quizas no se exatamente igual, pero a buen entendedor, pocos ejemplos hacen falta:

**Imagen:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Imagen:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El caso es **que los comentarios fueron borrados muy rapidamente** en cosa de segundos, posiblemente de no haber estado escribiendo mas texto en la pregunta que acababa de publicar, posiblemente no abria visto el comentario.

No solo el de @Ruben fue borrado sino tambien el mio, el mio se borro extremadamente rapido es mas no creo que a Ruben le llegar o si (si no es asi Ruben puedes mirar lo que te conteste en la imagen de arriba, quizas, si estabas aburrido podrias dedicar ese tiempo hacer algo productivo como mejorar tus codigos, leer un libro, no se algo productivo).

---

StackOverflow: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

**La falta de educación y el lenguaje de menosprecio no es correcto.**

> Lo grave es escribir azar con h :P – Rubén hace 5 minutos

Ami me parece que entra en ese punto. ¿no?.

**Tu lenguaje debe armonizar con la manera en la que hablas en persona a quien respetas y quien deseas que te respete.**

> Lo grave es escribir azar con h :P – Rubén hace 5 minutos

Ami me parece que entra en ese punto. ¿no?. Bueno si no entra en este punto, tengo unas preguntas para ti Rubén:

No creo que hables asi en el "mundo real", a todos y menos a gente que no conozcas, pero si hablas asi una pregunta. ¿Nunca te han partido la cara por tratar con menosprecio a los demas?.

O es que en los "foros" las normas basicas de educacion no se aplican porque se esta detras de una pantalla (muchos creen que el estar tras una pantalla le da el derecho ha hacer lo que quieran).

**Si no tienes el tiempo de decir algo cortés, déjalo para alguien que sí lo tenga.**

> Lo grave es escribir azar con h :P – Rubén hace 5 minutos

Ami me parece que entra en ese punto. ¿no?.

**Se acogedor, paciente, y de buenas intenciones.**

> Lo grave es escribir azar con h :P – Rubén hace 5 minutos

Ami me parece que entra en ese punto. ¿no?.

Si tanto te molestaba podrias haber borrado esa "h" en lugar de escribir mas de 20 caracteres en un comentario, aunque claro no se que esperabas que te contestara, en respuesta a tu comentario, pero las gracias no creo que fuera lo que estabas buscando.

---

En fin alguein dijo una vez:

**Si lo que vas a decir no es mas bonito que el silencio no digas nada.**

Por cierto tan culto que quieres mostrar que eres, ¿sabes que existe una cosa que se llama dislexia?.

- http://www.disfam.org/dislexia/
- https://changedyslexia.org/la-dislexia-y-las-faltas-de-ortografia/

Por si sigues sin entenderlo digamos que se tiene afectado un almacen visual donde se retiene la forma ortografica de las palabras por ello aunque se lea muchas veces una palabra no se automatiza su escritura y cuando esta palabra tiene grafonemas inconsistentes g/j, b/v, ll/y, **h**-… no se escriben de automatica de manera correcta sino que se tiene que pensar si se escribe de tal o cual modo.

P.D: No soy dislexico o quizas si, sea como fuera no creo que sea relevante en el contexto general de lo sucedido, podria ser que fuera, que mi idioma materno no es el español, o que simplemente tengo faltas de ortografia. Que pasa que este circulo de personas no pueden ser libres preguntar de la mejor manera que puedan sin que venga, algun Don Quijote a decir que esta mal y que no, a ojos de la RAE, y peor aun de una manera ofenciva.

Que facil es juzgar sin ponerse en la piel del otro, creo que esto ocurre mucho por aqui.

P.D <sub>1</sub>: Si hay faltas de ortografia no se cuantas pero seguro que varias, pero lo que no falta es educacion cuando escribo, eso si lo echaras en falta en mis textos, la falta de educacion.

Comment: Porque lo publico hoy, y no cuando paso (ayer), porque queria esperar haber si la moderaracion, tomaba alguna iniciativa sobre lo sucedido, al ver que no se tomaban las medidas minimas que yo esperaria, despues de mirar el chat no vi nada, tampoco ningun mensaje en el hilo de la pregunta afectada. Digo la moderacion, que algun moderador o alguien con poder para borrar comentarios esta al tanto de lo sucedido, y no se ha echo nada, ni se me ha comunicado que se han tomado medidas al respecto, ni siquiera se si piensan tomarlas y algunos despues dicen que quieren ejemplos...

Comment: Yo no hubiera expuesto (pues no me importa que me critiquen con educacion) o bien no se hubiera borrado los comentarios tanto el mio como el otro, el implicado y yo lo hubieramos discutido y fin, pero lo que molesta es que se trata de tapar y aqui no pasa nada, ni repercusiones ni nada, Ahh si solo pasa para los NO amigos, o con los que no estan deacuerdo con ciertas cosas, o simplemente a los que estan el la lista negra, si el sol sale sale para todos.Bueno espero les sirva el expuesto. Saludos.

Comment: ese usuario ya hizo una pregunta (la que se enlaza en el duplicado) y le comentamos y respondimos muchas personas. Le pedimos ejemplos no para tratarlo de loco si no porque frases como "Lo grave es escribir azar con h :P –" pueden para unos ser una ofensa y para otros no. Queremos saber lo que él consideraba rudo y arrogante. No dijo ejemplos (aunque sean borrados puedes citarlos como tú) en la primera pregunta y tampco en la duplicada

Comment: "*Lo cual se que es verdad, que existe este tipo de comportamientos, no todos actuan asi por suerte pero los hay, y lo que mas me molesta, es como se quiere tapar, la existencia de los mismos, casi dejando por loco al usuario/os que lo exponen*". Según tú pues, no se necesita prueba alguna de malos comportamientos y estos malos comportamientos existen sólo porque han sido señalados por un usuario. Pues sinceramente: no estoy de acuerdo. Por favor: pon ejemplos de lo que tú consideras malos comportamientos.

Comment: Solo puedo decir que esos comentarios parecía una discusión entre ustedes 2 que no aportaba al sitio, por ende fueron borrados. Fue una casualidad que lo vi cuando la publicación y los comentarios estaban frescos.

Comment: Posiblemente relacionado con esta pregunta: [Veo muchas publicaciones malas y me enoja muchísimo. ¿Qué debo hacer al respecto?](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/615/227)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yo creo que tiene que ver más con la que él mismo enlaza: [¿Por qué algunos miembros de aquí son arrogantes?](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/1360/15855) ya que la que propones menciona comentarios pero es basicamente sobre publicaciones de baja calidad

Comment: @lois6b yo considero que inclusive este tipo de actitudes en comentarios son publicaciones malas. Y como puse en la respuesta: "No dejes que lo que suceda en el sitio te afecte personalmente. Al final del día, solo es un pedazo de texto escrito en una página en internet. Brinda tu grano de arena en lo posible, y luego continúa con tu camino. (...) si los usuarios no quieren prestar atención, no tienen que lidiar con eso, acudan al moderador porque esa es parte de su labor: pelear contra los malos."

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza si bueno. este tipo de actitud es publicacion mala pero no todas las publicaciones malas son como esta acitud. puedes poner una publicacion "por favor hacedme los deberes" y no estar siendo arrogante ni irrespetuoso. sobre tu respuesta, chapó, tal cual lo que yo opino.

Comment: @lois6b por eso el "inclusive", es decir esto se debería agregar como publicación mala. De momento no tengo mucho tiempo para editar la pregunta y la respuesta para colocar un apartado particular sobre este tema, pero en cuanto lo tenga colocaré, o también otro usuario podría agregar dicha información en la pregunta y respuesta.

Comment: ¿Te estás quejando de como te contestó Rubén y quieres que lo castiguen de alguna manera? Es una queja muy, muy larga... Es un comportamiento específico de un usuario específico... no hay necesidad de generalizar. ¿Por qué no fue suficiente con reportar el o los comentarios que te afectaron?

Comment: No te calientes la cabeza. Si te insultan tu pasa, hombre.

Comment: Ah, y pregunta a gente de confianza. Tampoco desconfíes de la gente que te quiere ayudar, intenta conectar con ella y apoyar la página... o crea tú una nueva...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza *Solo puedo decir que esos comentarios parecía una discusión entre ustedes 2...* bueno yo no sabia quien los borro, pero ahora "creo" que se puede deir que sabes que existen comportamiento de este estilo tal como lo mencionaba/an otros usuarios a los que les pedian pruebas.Saludos

Comment: @toledano Te contesto, aunque no eres el unico que no entiende el trasfondo de la pregunta, eres el unico que en cierta manera a preguntado.*¿Te estás quejando de como te contestó Rubén...*digamos que en un 45% de la pregunta es por eso, ya comete *...lo hubieramos discutido y fin, pero lo que molesta es que se trata de tapar y aqui no pasa nada, ni repercusiones ni nada...* yo no hago esta pregunta por un comentario, sino por una actitud que veo en el sitio hacia algunos colectivos, y algunos creaban preguntas y les decian "...que si pruebas que si lo otro...".Asi que no quiero que castingen

Comment: a Ruben, aunque no es que apoye ese tipo de comentarios "seguro quedo claro que no apoyo" si se le prodria haber dicho algo al respecto como: "Mira Ruben ese comentario esta fuera de lugar aqui por que incita a bla bla..." mas que nada por evitar o sentar precedentes para otros usuarios que menosprecien a otros sin ser reinidentes dejen de hacerlo, y si son reincidentes pues medidas mas severas. -> *Es un comportamiento específico de un usuario específico...* si y no si solo fuera ami ese tipo comentario o esa actitud, seguramente no abria publicado en meta nada de esto...

Comment: ...(no digo que Ruben, que no lo se, se dedique a eso con todos lo usuarios) solo digo que para mi el fue el detonante. *¿Por qué no fue suficiente con reportar el o los comentarios que te afectaron?* Es posible que se te pasara que los comentarios **Fueron borrados** .Espero haber respondido a tus dudas. Saludos

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster espero no te enerves con este comentario mio -> *Según tú pues, no se necesita prueba alguna de malos comportamientos...* Que prueba va a necesitar un moderador/es etc. en el sitio que moderan cuando ellos estaran cansados de borrar comentarios de este tipo y es mas es posible que igual los puedan ver directamente en la pregunta afectada "especulo con lo ultimo", yo mismo he reportado decenas de estos tipo de comentarios. como usuario normal entenderia que nesecites pruebas pero no como moderador que me imagino que el autor se dirigia a alguien que puediera o debiera...

Comment: ... hacer algo. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel no me enervo. Pero me resulta chocante (y no en el buen sentido) que hables de malos comportamientos pero no aportes pruebas de ellos... no a los moderadores, si no al resto de la comunidad. Es como si quisieras comunicar que estos comportamientos existen tan sólo porque tú los denuncias; si fuesen comunes tendríamos más usuarios advirtiendo de lo mismo y no veo que sea así. Por lo tanto, insisto: ¿Puedes aportar ejemplos de lo que consideras malos comportamientos?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster cuando dices que se aporten ejemplos te refieres a mi caso? yo pensaba que te referias a los casos de las preguntas en lazadas, si es a mi caso deje unas capturas de pantalla sobre el comentario en cuestion, pero si es sobre las preguntas que enlaze no te puedo citar los comentarios a los que se refiere el autor pues entre otras nunca lei esa pregunta recien publicada "no estaba por el sitio". Sobre si puedo aportar ejemplos, pues si no quieres que me los invente no, pero si se que el flag...

Comment: de "irrespetuoso..." lo he usado varias veces para que la moderacion actuara en consecuecia. Espero haber contestado a tus preguntas/dudas. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel me refiero a todos los ejemplos que te están solicitando continuamente en las respuestas que has enlazado. Respecto a la captura que añades veo que efectivamente es una respuesta inadecuada, pero veo también inadecuada tu excesiva reacción a la misma. Esa respuesta no merecía reacción alguna, y si merecía alguna debía ser proporcional... **esto** es desproporcionado.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster -> me refiero a todos los ejemplos que te están solicitando continuamente en las respuestas que has enlazado... Quizas no te has dado cuenta (o yo no entendi bien) pero ami nadie me ha solicitado ningun ejemplo en la pregunta enlazada (la pregunta no es mia). *...tu excesiva reacción a la misma...* bueno eso depende de cada uno, hace una hora le conteste al usuario toledano, en este hilo, quizas te aclare mi punto de vista cuando dices "despropocionado". Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel me di cuenta que no te los solicitan a ti. Pero si te haces eco de esas preguntas: ¿qué menos que aportar los ejemplos de los que dichas preguntas carecían? Entiendo que estabas de acuerdo con la queja de las preguntas citadas, que carecían de ejemplos. Y si, considero tu reacción desproporcionada; un comentario antipático sobre tu ortografía no justifica toda esta reacción.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster -> *...que carecían de ejemplos* . Bueno en parte si cuando lo comento un usuario, pero no porque los necesitara (yo), porque yo se que estos comportamientos existen, sino porque es entendible que un usuario requiera de ejemplos, por eso puse el mio para que se entienda que estos comportamientos esta presente e intentar si no cortarlos si minimizarlos (los que existan y los que puedan llegar). -> *Y si, considero tu reacción desproporcionada* es tu opinion y es respetable, como la que pueda tener yo. Saludos y espero haber respondido a tus dudas.

Comment: No se trata de convencerme, se trata de convencer a otros lectores. Los participantes en esta comunidad o bien somos ingenieros, estudintes de ingeniería, técnicos en esta ingeniería o gente apasionada que independiente de su profesión está inmersa en este campo. Por ende, nos basamos en hechos para demostrar, no en opiniones. Sin hechos, mucho de lo que digas son simplemente palabras puestas en un texto de internet. Por eso siempre pido que pongan los hechos además que sirven para evidenciar si realmente tirnes razón en lo que dices o si estás equivocado.

Answer (score 5):

Como te dije [en un comentario a tu pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1443/se-va-ha-seguir-tapando-este-tipo-de-comportamientos-o-se-tiene-pensado-hacer-al#comment3988_1443) no intentamos **tapar** el comportamiento. Cada uno tiene una tolerancia maxima, una personalidad e incluso un tipo de humor.

El comentario de Ruben que mencionas deberia resbalarte tanto si su intención es criticar (que conociendo al usuario lo dudo) o si su intención es hacer una pequeña broma.

---

[La respuesta que se le dio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1365/15855) a ese usuario de Meta, bien valdría para tu caso.

En internet hay muchos tipos de personas, y entre ellas personas que desean el mal (no hablo de ti, Ruben ). Van a criticar tu manera de escribir, tus preguntas, tus respuestas, tu conocimiento, tu nombre de usuario o a saber.

Tu **pasa de todo**. Lo que tienes que hacer es reportar el comentario y si lo consideras oportuno avisar a un moderador. Céntrate en los comentarios que si aportan algo a tu pregunta.

Un saludo

Comment: *El comentario de Ruben que mencionas deberia resbalarte tanto si su intención es criticar...intención es hacer una pequeña broma* en serio me dices eso veo y ves ese tipo de comportamientos normal y que no tiene que ser tenidos en cuenta a Ruben o a quien sea.*Tu pasa de todo* ah si, veo que tampoco entendistes la pregunta te aclaro" Esto no es solo por eso comentario, ni tampoco por ser solo hacia mi, es por una actitud que esta pasando en el sitio",si yo paso de todo, al otro que se lo hagan tambien tiene que pasar de todo tambien.

Comment: *Lo que tienes que hacer es reportar el comentario...* se te paso que los comentarios fueron borrados ect...*si lo consideras oportuno avisar a un moderador. Céntrate en los comentarios que si aportan algo a tu pregunta.* -> seguramente no lo haces queriendo pero **En serio**, si te digo por ejemplo:  Que tu respuesta es una basura, esta precisamente que ha sido relizada para ganar votos de una pregunta polemica. Seguro que no piensas igual. ("aunque quizas me equivoque"). Saludos

Answer (score -3):

Sí, claro que va a seguir sucediendo. No se puede poner al lobo a vigilar las ovejas.

No esperes soluciones de los moderadores (quizás de Miquel Coll sí, pero para uno solo es demasiado). La negación de los problemas es la tónica habitual, incluso en casos en que el moderador mismo [ha dicho explícitamente que algo está mal](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1416/respuesta-borrada-y-duplicada#comment3853_1416). Véase [Respuesta borrada y duplicada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1416/respuesta-borrada-y-duplicada) donde otra vez la usuaria [reincide](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/49630/301) (van 3 veces) y el haberla reportado no ha servido de nada.

La brigada de cierre de preguntas seguirá cerrando preguntas a los nuevos usuarios dificultando así el crecimiento del sitio. Pero cuando en vez de quejarte intentes colaborar en mejorar la situación pues te [van a cerrar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1435/existe-alguna-propuesta-para-intentar-solucionar-estos-numeros) con cualquier excusa. Y no la comunidad, no es que 5 voten para cerrar, no. Cerrado con privilegio de moderador, que para eso sí que se mueve.

Lo que puedes esperar de este moderador es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Mientras Mendoza piense que parte de su labor consiste en pelear con algunos usuarios mal estamos. Mal asunto que vea a parte de la base de usuarios como los malos. No es una novedad, otras palabras despectivas ha usado en el pasado para referirse a parte de los usuarios. [No es la primera vez que se llama la atención sobre este asunto](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/800/para-cuando-unas-elecciones-para-tener-un-moderador-moderado).

Comment: Bueno y ¿que es lo que deseas? **¿que eliminen mi cuenta?, ¿que eliminen a un moderador?** , Ese comentario, "No se puede poner al lobo a vigilar las ovejas." me parece demasiado soez de tu parte creo que es bueno exigir cosas pero tratando de ser más educado. La pregunta no es en relación a mí pero tu respuesta parece ser enfocada a mi nuevamente... que  raro =) http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1416/respuesta-borrada-y-duplicada

Comment: El cierre de preguntas y respuestas es obvia dentro de la tarea de un moderador cuando son malas y no contribuyen al objetivo del sitio, por ejemplo ve esta respuesta y las que se han cerrado que tu has realizado... =(

Comment: Sequimos con los insultos. Ahora JorgeSys usa soez para referirse a mis actos. [Soez](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YDWmJ3u): adj. Bajo, grosero, indigno, vil.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos gracias por tomarte el tiempo de contestar. *La brigada de cierre de preguntas seguirá cerrando preguntas a los nuevos usuarios dificultando así el crecimiento del sitio.* no puedo estar mas de acuerdo con esto es una cosa que veo casi a diario y algunas veces hasta mas. Saludos