# Una teoría de moderación

Tags: discusión, moderación, artículo

> Traducción de [A Theory of Moderation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/)
>
> Se ha agregado ♦ para destacar que se habla de los moderadores de la Comunidad ya sea Pro Tempore o elegidos y diferenciarlos de los usuarios con privilegios de moderación obtenidos por los puntos de reputación ganados.

---

Creemos profundamente en la moderación comunitaria. Es por eso que nombramos [Moderadores Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) e, idealmente, [moderadores democráticamente elegidos](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-exchange-moderator-elections-begin/) para cada sitio de nuestra red. Pero, ¿qué hacen los moderadores comunitarios (N. del T. moderadores ♦)? La respuesta corta es: **¡lo menos posible!**

Desde la primera versión de [FAQ de Stack Overflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) a mediados de 2008, nuestra meta siempre ha sido devolver el poder a la comunidad:

> ¡Stack Overflow es dirigido por ti! Si quieres ayudarnos a que Stack Overflow funcione, necesitarás primero reputación. La reputación es una medida (muy) aproximada de cuánto confía la comunidad de Stack Overflow en ti. La reputación nunca se da, se gana por convencer a otros usuarios de Stack Overflow de que sabes de lo que estás hablando.

Diseñamos el motor de la [red Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/sites) para que sea en su mayoría autorregulado, ya que amortizamos el costo de moderación global del sistema a través de miles de pequeños retoques de esfuerzo aportados por los usuarios regulares y cotidianos. Específicamente, por los [privilegios de reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges):

- Los usuarios con 15 puntos de reputación pueden reportar mensajes.
- Los usuarios con 500 puntos de reputación pueden revisar los mensajes de nuevos usuarios.
- Los usuarios con 2000 puntos de reputación pueden editar cualquier pregunta o respuesta.
- Los usuarios con 3000 puntos de reputación pueden emitir votos de cierre y reapertura.
- Los usuarios con 10 000 puntos de reputación pueden emitir votos de eliminación y recuperación en preguntas y tienen acceso a un panel de moderación.
- Los usuarios con 15 000 puntos de reputación pueden proteger publicaciones.
- Los usuarios con 20 000 puntos de reputación pueden emitir votos de eliminación en las respuestas con votos negativos.

Incluso con la auto-regulación activa de la comunidad, los moderadores ♦ ocasionalmente necesitan intervenir. Los **moderadores ♦ son manejadores de excepciones humanos**, para hacer frente a esas (con suerte raras) condiciones excepcionales que *normalmente* no deberían ocurrir, pero que cuando lo hacen pueden provocar un gran grito a toda la comunidad - *si* no existe un manejo humano de excepciones a punto.

La tarea más común del moderador ♦ es el seguimiento de las [publicaciones reportadas](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/improved-flagging/). Cada publicación contiene un **enlace para reportar**, que puede utilizar cualquier persona con 15 puntos de reputación.

[image]

Las publicaciones pueden ser marcadas como spam, ofensivas o simplemente de forma general "necesita atención de un moderador ♦" con un comentario explicativo o enlace.

[image: Estoy marcando esto porque ...]

Una vez marcado, una publicación incrementa un número contador que aparece en la barra superior de cada moderador ♦.

[image]

**Si ves ve algo en el sistema que es malo, extraño, o excepcional de alguna manera y merece la atención del moderador ♦ por cualquier motivo ... *[¡repórtalo!](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)***. Ese es el trabajo principal de un moderador ♦ : mirar cada publicación marcada, y tomar medidas si es necesario.

Los moderadores ♦ también tienen algunas habilidades especiales necesarias para manejar esas poco frecuentes condiciones excepcionales:

- Los votos de los moderadores ♦ son vinculantes. Cualquier lugar en el que tengamos votación - cerrar, abrir, borrar, borrar, ofensiva, migración, etc. - ese voto alcanzará el umbral y surtirá efecto *inmediatamente* si un solo moderador ♦ emite un voto.
- Los moderadores ♦ pueden bloquear los mensajes. Los mensajes bloqueados no pueden ser votados ni modificados de ninguna manera.
- Los moderadores ♦ pueden [proteger las preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions). Las preguntas protegidas sólo permiten respuestas de usuarios con más de 10 reputación.
- Los moderadores ♦ pueden ver más datos en el sistema, incluyendo las estadísticas de voto (pero no "quiénes votaron para esta publicación") y la información del perfil de usuario.
- Los moderadores ♦ pueden [suspender temporalmente](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) a los usuarios y eliminarlos si es necesario.
- Los moderadores ♦ pueden realizar acciones de mantenimiento a gran escala, como la fusión de preguntas y etiquetas, las aprobaciones de sinónimos de etiquetas, y así sucesivamente.

Así que, en resumen, si eres es un moderador ♦ de la comunidad en un sitio de Stack Exchange, esto es lo que puedes esperar:

- Como moderador ♦ tus acciones ahora representan a la comunidad, por lo que estarás sujeto a un nivel muy alto de comportamiento. Eres un embajador de confianza, con los mismos derechos que el equipo oficial de desarrollo y los coordinadores de la comunidad.
- Tu objetivo es **guiar a la comunidad con una intervención suave pero firme**. Respeta a tus compañeros miembros de la comunidad en todo momento; demuestra justicia e imparcialidad en tus acciones.
- Siempre que sea posible, **trata de dejar comentarios frecuentes en las publicaciones en las que has tomado (o considerado tomar) una acción de moderador ♦**, explicando el razonamiento. Esto es importante para que los miembros de la comunidad puedan aprender las normas de la comunidad y las políticas de moderación.
- Mantén el sitio razonablemente en el tema **cerrando, migrando, o eliminando preguntas descaradamente fuera del tema**.
- Comprueba periódicamente si hay **mensajes reportados** y decide si es necesario tomar más acciones.
- En el caso de disputas serias, **comunícate directamente con los usuarios vía correo electrónico** para ayudar a mediar y resolver esas disputas.

Si bien ser moderador de la comunidad (N. del T. moderador ♦) es un voluntario (pero a menudo *elegido*), y la participación es estrictamente voluntaria en todo momento, hay tres cosas importantes que pedimos a todos los moderadores de la comunidad elegidos:

- Debes aceptar el [acuerdo de moderador de la comunidad](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement) en los 30 primeros días desde la elección o nombramiento y permanecer activo en el sitio.
- Debes mantener la comunicación con los compañeros moderadores y trabajar con ellos para resolver cualquier desacuerdo dentro del equipo. [Hay un proceso](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/151606/handling-calls-to-remove-a-moderator/157258#157258) para que un equipo retire a los moderadores ♦ que no pueden o no quieren cooperar.
- Sobre Stack Overflow, debido a su tamaño y escala inmensos, hay otro requisito. Si pasas tiempo en el sitio participando pero no estás resolviendo los reportes con regularidad, puede que debar ceder tu derecho a seguir siendo un moderador de la comunidad.

Una gran parte del trabajo de moderación es extremadamente mundano, casi de limpieza. Consiste en eliminar el spam obvio, cerrar las preguntas claramente fuera de tema y eliminar algunos de los peores mensajes clasificados en varias dimensiones.

El moderador ♦ ideal hace lo menos posible. Pero esas pequeñas acciones pueden ser poderosas y altamente concentradas. Limitando de manera juiciosa el uso de los poderes del moderador ♦ para podar selectivamente y guiar a la comunidad - *ese* es el verdadero arte de la moderación.

Comment: +1 Confieso que la teoría de la moderación es lo que mas me gusta de sois, después de las preguntas y respuestas =)

Comment: @toledano: Me sumo a la confesión.

Comment: Faltaría cambiar las capturas por las del sitio en español... Además esas imágenes son muy viejas, esa barra azul tiene pinta de la década del 80.

Comment: Si bien me tomé la libertad de agregar los ♦ cuando se menciona el término moderador, las imágenes no las actualicé, en primer lugar por tiempo pero también porque el tema central es la parte teórica de la moderación, no la parte operativa, para esta parte tenemos los artículos de ayuda y los [meta-tag:faq].

Comment: Hablando del [meta-tag:faq] todavía faltan muchos por traducir. Véase [¿Sabes inglés, quieres aportar a la comunidad de SOes y no sabes cómo? ¡Traduce un FAQ!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1380/65) cc @ArtEze

Comment: La lógica de los sitios de SE es que se genere contenido de calidad entre todos... Quien quiera y tenga el tiempo puede modificar las imágenes.

Comment: Una definición sobre el trabajo del moderador que me parece muy acertada: _supposedly, they should only act when the community doesn't seems to be able to handle it itself. Exception handlers are for exceptional circumstances_ ([fuente](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351972/2017-moderator-election-qa-question-collection?cb=1#comment491031_351972))

Comment: HTML de imágenes reemplazado por copia de las imágenes correspondientes.