# ¿Qué ocurre con la pregunta "Manejar conexiones a bases de datos MySQL mediante PDO: principios básicos"?

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas, revisión-de-pregunta

Sencillamente quisiera saber el motivo por el cual [preguntas como esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/81028/29967) no pueden existir en Stack Overflow en español.

Después de haber sido puesta en espera fue reabierta, y luego puesta en espera de nuevo por otro moderador.

No sé si ha habido un abuso de autoridad con respecto a esta pregunta, la cual, por cierto, me ha tomado su tiempo en la traducción.

Luego, alguien vota para eliminarla, sin siquiera explicar el motivo.

Realmente, es algo molesto.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. Tremendo trabajo hiciste. Veamos opiniones y probablemente sería bueno reabrirla o trocearla. De verdad, necesitamos [Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation).

Comment: Mi voto para el cierre, junto al de otros, fue acompañado de un comentario, que ahora está en el chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38349154#38349154.

Comment: Acabo de ver lo de Documentation, quizá necesitamos algo así en SOes, pero no veo tampoco correcto que una respuesta a una pregunta tenga el tamaño de la que ha hecho A. Cedano

Comment: En ese caso el término _Wiki de comunidad_ no es correcto y se presta a confusión. Yo mismo creía que una respuesta Wiki podía ser del tamaño de una enciclopedia.

Comment: La pregunta es muy amplia. Punto final.

Comment: No considero que la pregunta sea amplia y en cuanto a la respuesta es Wiki de comunidad. Punto final en lo que a ti respecta @toledano .

Comment: Yo creo que te vendría bien hacer un blog... donde estarás libre de comentar cualquier librería existente de este planeta y quizás tendrías más aceptación... O esperar que salga [Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) en Spanish...

Comment: Como ya han comentado, la comunidad es la que decide, te guste o no, la opinión de todos cuenta, pero si la mayor parte de la comunidad cree que una pregunta debería ser cerrada sera cerrada. Creo que el sitio precisamente destaca por esto mismo, porque es la comunidad quien acaba decidiendo el futuro de una pregunta, y no una sola persona como al parecer pretendes hacerlo tu (evidentemente habrá gente que opine como tu).

Comment: @Victor-Random al parecer hay otras 6 personas que están de acuerdo conmigo, un poco extraño eso entonces. ¿podrías por favor decirme como se comenta con más respeto o de forma más "madura"? Sobretodo la última parte. Gracias. Si quieres nos citamos en el chat y me lo explicas.

Comment: @Shaz no se como invitar a un chat xD, jejeje, me explico mejor, la cosa no esta tanto en la pregunta, si debe ser cerrada esta bien, sino que me parece que cuando comentas usas argumentos que pueden ofender a la persona, en un primer momento dijiste que no estabamos en la inquisicion, y ahora sacas el comentario de que cedano es el pastor que no se que cosa y que aparte es un ser superior, desde mi punto de vista eso es buscar que se sienta ofendido o molestarlo, no me refiero al echo de que opines que se cierre la pregunta :).

Comment: @Shaz algo mas maduro seria evitar ese tipo de comentario e ir directo a tu opinion en cuanto a la pregunta, para mi solo esto bastaria: " 
Aún si te parece molesto y crees que realmente tienes la razón (y no dudo de tus buenas intenciones), pero la comunidad es la que decide, independiente que te guste o no. "

Comment: @Victor-Random agradezco tu respuesta y espero algún día tener tu madurez. En todo caso, si alguien tiene alguna queja de mi comportamiento en la comunidad, puede reportarlo a un moderador.

Comment: @Shaz solo es un consejo de mi parte (y)

Comment: Si alguna de las respuestas te sirvió, puedes marcarla como correcta.

Comment: @ArtEze Ninguna respuesta me ha servido en sí. Este caso me ha servido en general para sacar mis propios conclusiones sobre el _espíritu_ que impera en dos o tres usuarios de esta comunidad, quienes al parecer marcan las pautas de la misma. El problema no era la pregunta en sí, la prueba es que la misma ha sido modificada cumpliendo las supuestas _normas_ de SO, sin embargo permanece cerrada. He sacado mis propias conclusiones, las cuales quizá exponga en algún momento, si lo considero útil.

Comment: @A.Cedano todos mis comentarios fueron en cuanto a la pregunta en sí. Recién veo este comentario tuyo. Sin embargo, no veo que hayas pubicado nada que muestre que la modificaste. Tus útimas 2 ediciones no la enviaron a la cola de reapertura, y la publicación está actualmente bloqueada, por lo que no se puede votar para reabrir... Sos un usuario que tiene acceso a ver estas cosas, ¿cómo podíamos enterarnos de que la modificaste??

Comment: @Mariano por mi parte he abandonado el caso, por un motivo muy sencillo. Este tipo de contribuciones, requieren su tiempo el prepararlas. Mi actividad principal no es la programación, por lo que no puedo estar todo el tiempo en esto. Si encima de invertir un tiempo considerable preparando cierto contenido tengo que invertir más tiempo todavía para que sea considerado, reconsiderado, abierto, reabierto. La _comunidad_ (o mejor dicho 4 ó 5 miembros muy activos de la _comunidad_)  decidió que no quiere ese tipo de contenido. Esa es la conclusión a la que he llegado.

Comment: @A.Cedano entiendo tu punto de vista. Es totalmente respetable, y agradezco el tiempo que ya dedicás en aportar contenido. Sólo creía que la conclusión a la que llegaste, que sigue cerrada después de la modificación, tiene que considerar que creo que en realidad es porque nunca fue evaluada. Me parece que la respuesta de la comunidad luego de tu edición podría ser diferente, no lo sé.

Comment: Como te decía, @Mariano, para mí significa invertir demasiado tiempo en algo que no va a ser valorado en su justa medida. He estado leyendo un poco sobre SO y hay varios ex-usuarios y usuarios activos desilusionados. Aquí mismo en Meta, en una pregunta que versaba sobre no convertir SO en un blog, a la que yo también respondí, quedó claro que esos 4 ó 5 usuarios conducen a esta comunidad por el camino del declive. Podrías leer [esto](https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d) cuando puedas, y también [esto](https://phpdelusions.net). Mi experiencia coincide con ambos.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya las había leído, gracias, y sé desde donde lo estás diciendo. Hay puntos que comparto y otros que no (sería una discusión larga)... Puedo ver muchas cosas en lo que decís que estaría bueno seguir reviendo, y algunos criterios de cierre a revisar, así como opiniones de la comunidad que creo que estaría bueno que consideres. Eso sí, no acuerdo con que sean 4 o 5 que conducen la comunidad, ni creo que lo estén llevando al declive. Pero entendí tu punto de vista.

Comment: Eso lo dirá el tiempo @Mariano. Al menos en mi caso, quienes cierran las preguntas son casi siempre los mismos y por lo que he podido ver, en otros  casos, también. Cuando una pregunta es cerrada el sistema indica que sea modificada para reconsiderar la apertura. No creo, sinceramente, que quienes cierran preguntas (en general) se impongan la responsabilidad de volver más tarde sobre esas preguntas para reconsiderar la apertura. Este mismo es un ejemplo de ello.

Comment: Sería interesante que @ArtEze explicase el por qué de esto: _Esta pregunta existe porque tiene importancia histórica, **pero no se la considera una buena pregunta relacionada con el tema en cuestión para este sitio, así que no la utilices como evidencia de que puedes formular preguntas similares aquí.** Esta pregunta y sus respuestas están congeladas y no se pueden modificar._ Si vemos bien, la pregunta ha sido modificada para adaptarse al sitio. Sin embargo, ahora esta cerrada y además con esta _horrible_ nota, la cual no entiendo. Son cosas que reafirman lo que pienso sobre SO.

Comment: @A.Cedano hay algunas excepciones que no la mandan a reapertura (por ejemplo, tus últimas 2 ediciones en la pregunta en cuestión, podés verlo en el timeline). Y en breve (10k) vas a poder ver el historial de revisiones de reapertura. Sin dedicarle mucho análisis, te diría que quienes revisan cierre también están activos en reapertura, pero pronto nos dirás ;-)

Comment: @A.Cedano La pregunta la terminé bloqueando para que no sea eliminada en un futuro. Mi opinión personal es que debería quedar abierta, pero como moderador no debo interferir con la decisión de Luiggi.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el motivo por el que debe ser eliminada @Artze? No lo entiendo. La forma en que se están moderando las cosas ayudan a empobrecer más este sitio.

Comment: @A.Cedano Todo lo contrario... Me llegó un reporte diciendo que para evitar que sea eliminada, la publicación debía bloquearse, y acepté.

Comment: @ArtEze me parece que es algo incongruente. Si se actúa con recta intención, quien la marcó para eliminación pienso que debería al menos indicar el motivo. Tú ejecutaste la acción de bloquearla para que no sea eliminada, de acuerdo, pero la nota que se pone (la cual imagino es automática) es confusa y le quita credibilidad y valor a la pregunta: _Esta pregunta existe porque tiene importancia histórica, **pero no se la considera una buena pregunta relacionada con el tema en cuestión para este sitio, así que no la utilices como evidencia de que puedes formular preguntas similares aquí.**_

Comment: @A.Cedano Es un mensaje automático. En lo personal me gustó la publicación, pero generalmente a la gente no le gusta que en la pregunta falte código, debe ser eso.

Answer (score 7):

Desgraciadamente, creo que el enfoque de la pregunta es erroneo.

Cuando alguien llega a este sitio a preguntar, no va a leer una respuesta que le ocupa 25 monitores como documentación. desgraciadamente la mayoría que llego acá, no lee ni piensa leer eso, y quiere la respuesta a su problema en particular. Por lo tanto, escribir un manual así sirve para nosotros, pero no para los que preguntan. y si su pregunta esta contestada ahí, ponerle un link no va a servir de nada, porque lo único que vamos a lograr es espantarlo.

Es hermoso que te hayas tomado el tiempo en traducir todo eso, pero si esto estuviera en un blog seria mejor... La gente que lo va a ver, es aquella que tenga la capacidad de entender de lo que estas hablando.
La gente va a seguir preguntando por todo eso que escribiste, y es mas, lo desgraciado de escribir algo así, es que es difícil de validar si lo que esta escrito se entiende para un usuario con un nivel de conocimiento X...
por eso tenemos a veces preguntas similares, con enfoques de respuestas distintos...

La pregunta es amplia (totalmente, empieza diciendo principios basicos) y lleva a una respuesta, que es un capitulo de un libro. Entiendo que no hay mala intención en ningún lado por parte de nadie, pero me parece que permitir esto abre una puerta difícil de cerrar.

Comment: Suscribo. Respuestas concretas a preguntas concretas. Si tengo que leer un libro para encontrar la respuesta a una pregunta básica, no me sirve. Y recordemos que al proponer una pregunta para cierre, votamos por la pregunta, no por la respuesta o por el binomio pregunta/respuesta. Solo se vota la respuesta.

Comment: @toledano Imagino que quieres decir que solo se vota cerrar la pregunta.

Comment: Esta respuesta nos lleva a : Los angloparlantes pueden tener Stack Overflow Documentation y los hispanoparlantes no podemos.

Comment: Los angloparlantes nos llevan 10 años de ventaja y todavia estan viendo q hacer con documentation.. creo q hasta q ellos q son muchos mas no se decidas, nosotros q estamos en pañales no podemos decir ni mu

Comment: Nosotros podemos decir lo que nos apetezca. Y podemos aspirar a ser más que ellos. Posiblemente no en todo, pero no sería tan raro que hiciésemos algo mejor que ellos y nos lo copien.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos: No esta respuesta no nos lleva a eso. Lo que nos lleva a eso es que Stack Overflow tiene su sede en los EEUU y recursos limitados.

Comment: @Rubén Tienes mucha razón Rubén. Por eso tenemos que hacerlo nosotros si lo queremos.

Comment: Sí, yo creo que podemos encontrar una forma para que la comunidad de [es.so] colabore en proyectos de documentación extensos.

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo. Por un solo motivo: quienes estén dispuestos a colaborar con contenido extenso actualmente se podrían contar con los dedos de una mano. Aunque a algunos les moleste seré franco: la comunidad de programadores hispanos no es solamente pequeña, sino también perezosa y de escasa visión. Por eso estamos y al parecer seguiremos estando, como estamos. Y por cierto, leer no es perjudicial para la salud si el contenido es bueno.

Comment: @A.Cedano Hombre... Incluso aunque tuvieses razon... Se me ocurren pocas formas mejores de sabotear el esfuerzo por que este contenido se permita en el sitio que llamar a la comunida de programadores hispanos pequeña, perezosa y de escasa visión.

Comment: Exacto @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos, eso quise escribir. Solo se vota la pregunta.

Comment: @toledano ¿Y la respuesta que te parece? ¿Te gusta? Y si te gusta, ¿hay alguna forma de reescribir la pregunta para que sea aceptable?

Comment: La respuesta me parece demasiado extensa para el formato de la comunidad. No se trata de demostrar erudición, sino de resolver un problema concreta con una respuesta puntual.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos he hablado con franqueza. Es lo que pienso y por eso lo he dicho.

Answer (score 5):

#### Estado actual de la pregunta

Intenté leer con detenimiento toda la respuesta y no pude. Supongo que soy uno de esos *millennials* que no son capaces de leer más de dos pantallas de texto antes de perder la paciencia. Sin embargo, sí soy lector frecuente de blogs y lugares en los que hay unos enlaces ordenaditos y cada vez tomo una u otra sección para leer con detenimiento. Al fin y al cabo, normalmente llego a esos lugares con alguna duda puntual, no en busca de una explicación exhaustiva (en cuyo caso suelo preferir un libro).

Pese a que se ha pedido algunas veces, por el momento la interfaz de Stack Exchange no permite enlaces internos dentro de una página. Esto imposibilita crear secciones en una pregunta y enlazarlas en un índice inicial.

Todo esto lo comento porque creo que tu dupla pregunta-respuesta es una fantástica pieza de contenido (hasta donde leí, pero conociéndote sé que pones empeño en que lo que escribes sea siempre útil y bien documentado): mezclas teoría con práctica al abordar los temas que has visto que son los que más problemas generan en la gente que visita Stack Overflow en español. Es, por tanto, una muy buena guía de usuario.

#### Sugerencia de mejora

El punto de toda esta digresión es que creo que una solución limpia, útil y fácil es cortar cada una de las secciones y generar pregunta-respuesta con ellas. Así, para el capítulo:

> 2.5 Contando filas con PDO

Podrías tener una pregunta del tipo:

> ¿Cómo se cuentan las filas con PDO?

Y así con todas las secciones que veo (y que observo que ahora está reducido tras tu [última edición](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/81029/14)).

Después, añade el listado de preguntas a la wiki de las etiquetas correspondientes.

#### Abriendo un poco más el foco: ¿cómo abordar estos problemas?

Creo que debemos escapar de trabajar como llaneros solitarios. Me explico: observo a veces (incluso en mí) que detectamos un problema y corremos solos a resolverlo. Eso puede ser útil en casos concretos, pero en general abogo más por la máxima de **organízate y lucha**. En una comunidad autogestionada como esta, tal enfoque toma más relevancia: si no consigues cierto consenso en que tu propuesta es útil, la comunidad va a votarla negativamente, cerrarla o incluso borrarla. ¡Y eso da mucha rabia!
Por tanto, creo que un paso previo debería haber consistido en plantear la idea de pregunta canónica aquí en Meta. Recabar opiniones de otros expertos en el tema, definir una idea de cómo enfocarlo... y finalmente proceder a publicar. Así tendrías una masa crítica de colaboradores dispuestos a mejorar la publicación, en lugar de detractores que la vieran como un esfuerzo titánico... pero en una dirección diferente a la que consideran útil.

#### Casos de éxito (para mí)

Durante unos años he sido un respondedor regular de preguntas de Bash y awk en Stack Overflow. Con el tiempo se generó un grupito de usuarios regulares, con medalla de oro para cerrar como duplicados y con ganas de limpiar, fijar y dar esplendor a esas etiquetas.

Con el tiempo, especialmente en Bash, fuimos poblando la [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) con una lista de preguntas recurrentes y eligiendo (en este caso en el chat) cuál podía ser la canónica para usarla como destino de los duplicados. Una vez bien elaboradas y definidas, en la mayoría de etiquetas te das cuenta que un 80% de las preguntas acaban siendo repetitivas y, medalla de oro mediante, los usuarios típicos pueden hacer una buena labor marcando como duplicados cuando sea necesario. Hubo también casos en que detectamos que no había ninguna pregunta concreta *canonizable*, por lo que entonces -y solo entonces- procedimos a crearla nosotros mismos.

Bash y awk en este sentido no difieren demasiado de MySQL, PHP y PDO, las etiquetas de tu pregunta. Intenta/intentad/intentemos crear un grupo de usuarios con objetivos comunes y trabajemos en ese sentido. De lo contrario seguiremos con peleas fratricidas que solo llevarán al descontento.

#### Sobre la gestión de la apertura y cierre

Creo que los moderadores no han actuado bien como colectivo. Uno de ellos votó para reabrir y otro para cerrar. Al contar con votos todopoderosos, en cada ocasión eso decantó la balanza.

Si bien es bueno tener moderadores vinculados a las decisiones de la Comunidad, creo que en casos así deben intervenir si es de forma organizada y consensuada. De lo contrario, están transmitiendo a la comunidad que quien debe velar por definir los límites... no los tiene del todo claros.

Siempre mantendré mi gran agredecimiento a los moderadores por ofrecernos su valioso tiempo y eso está por encima de todo. Lo que también pienso es que es necesario que sean más transparentes en su decisiones e interactúen más entre ellos para [*podar selectivamente y guiar a la comunidad*](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2227/83).

Comment: Qué irónico: ante una respuesta tan larga, mi propuesta para mejorarla es una respuesta.. larguísima :O

Comment: Todos los consejos son excelentes y estoy totalmente de acuerdo con ellos, más viniendo de una experiencia como la de organizar una etiqueta en SO... Sin embargo, no estás tocando el tema de esta discusión: la *pregunta* (no la *respuesta*). Supongo que es intencional (basta con ver el primer título y la primera oración) porque ahí está el problema, pero intentando seguir tu respuesta, creo que la recomendación de buscar consenso incluiría en primer lugar que lo ayuden a definir el alcance de cada tópico.

Comment: En cuanto a moderadores. La verdad es que venimos viendo cómo están jugando a [María La Paz](https://jaenpedia.wikanda.es/wiki/Juegos_populares_de_Bail%C3%A9n#Mar.C3.ADa_la_Paz), con algunos ejemplos que no se sabe si es para reir o para llorar, y eso impacta en la imagen del sitio (ya habrá elecciones)... En este caso, creo que el cierre corrigió una mala acción que se había tomado previamente por inexperiencia.

Comment: @Mariano sí, omití el tema de la pregunta porque me parece menos relevante que el resto de la discusión. Hacer _on topic_ una pregunta con autorespuesta debería ser tan fácil como añadir un enunciado algo genérico pero que defina bien el tema.

Comment: Muy de acuerdo con fedorqui. El problema no es la pregunta sino la forma en que se recibe la respuesta. Algunos ya han manifestado que no les gusta la respuesta, la ven muy larga, y que no hay ninguna forma de redactar una pregunta para esa respuesta con la que estuviesen de acuerdo. Dicho con otras palabras, se rechaza hacer Documentation en SOes. Si esa es la opinión mayoritaria, de momento así parece, tendrá que ser así. Y mientras dure esta coyuntura la única salida que veo es la misma que propone fedorqui: trocear.

Comment: @JoseA entiendo tu punto de vista, y leí muchas de las *historias* que te dan argumentos para esas conclusiones. El tema es que en este caso yo fui uno de los que votó para cerrar, y te aseguro que el problema ***es*** la pregunta. También creo que con una pregunta *concreta*, la respuesta pueda terminar siendo un poco más acotada -no lo sé. Estoy en contra de un Documentation, y al mismo tiempo deseando ver más contenido como la respuesta de A.Cedano, siempre que dé lugar a otras respuestas. Que la respuesta a la pregunta no esté limitado al aporte, la visión y las formas de una sola persona.

Comment: @Mar el texto actual es _Dado que PDO es una de las clases recomendadas por PHP para manejar nuestras conexiones a las bases de datos MySQL (la otra es MySQLi), y sabiendo que la extensión `mysql_*` es desde hace un tiempo obsoleta. Quisiera saber cómo consultar a una base de datos de forma segura mediante PDO y cómo leer los datos obtenidos en la consulta. Si es posible, sería útil una respuesta que indique con claridad en cuáles casos se debe usar consultas preparadas y en cuales no._ A mí me parece correcto y no problemático, así como superfluos los otros dos párrafos. ¿Qué te parece a ti?

Comment: @fedorqui estás citando al texto, luego de ser modificado recientemente (y que yo no había leído). El texto sobre el cual se preguntó originalmente, y sobre el cual estaba opinando está en https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/81028/3

Comment: @Mariano caramba, es complicado opinar sobre algo que cambia tan rápido :D Coincido contigo en que el redactado que mencionas no cumple lo descrito en [ask]. Además, incide en la _manía_ de incluir cosas Meta en el propio enunciado (_se responderá..._, _lo que me ha motivado..._). Dicho lo cual, el enunciado actual sí me gusta y cuando llegue a 3000 puntos me gustará votar para reabrirla.

Answer (score -3):

**Stack Overflow será lo que nosotros queramos que sea**. Es una máxima que se ha repetido muchas veces. Y este es un buen momento para demostrarlo.

¿Queremos esto en el sitio? Yo sí lo quiero. De hecho me gustaría que hubiese más.
¿Perjudica a alguien este contenido? ¿Disminuye la calidad del sitio? ¿Lo hace menos mantenible? No, no y no.

Si existiese [Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) en español entonces estaría totalmente de acuerdo en cerrar y borrar la pregunta y respuesta de Cedano. Pero no existe ni va a existir a corto o medio plazo. Por eso pienso que debemos dar cabida a este contenido en SOes, que es lo único que tenemos y vamos a tener en la red de SO.

Esto tiene un inconveniente. Si admitimos la pregunta amplia de Cedano hay que admitirlas todas y yo tampoco quiero que el sitio se llene de preguntas amplias sin respuesta. La solución que propongo: permitir las preguntas autorrespondidas sin limite en cuanto a amplitud. La limitación de amplitud existe para resolver un problema que no se presenta en las preguntas autorrespondidas, el tener preguntas que no se pueden responder o es demasiado difícil responder.

**Quienes han votado por cerrar han actuado de forma correcta** según las normas del sitio actuales. Nada que objetarles.
**Llamo a que mejoremos esas normas en beneficio de todos.**

Comment: Me parece una decisión correcta.

Comment: En cuanto a Documentation, claro, sería buenísimo tener más documentación en español, y posiblemente una herramienta/nuevo sitio que promueva esto, mejor aún si tiene éxito. Sin embargo, "Documentation de SO", en mi opinión (y la de muchos), no ha sido un buen formato y no ha tenido mucho éxito por ahora y se está evaluando cambiarlo. Es una discusión que se escapa del alcance de esta respuesta, pero sí te pido tener en cuenta que ese producto en particular quizás no sea la mejor solución para el problema de cómo generar documentación en español. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349410/5290909

Comment: En cuanto a tu propuesta, lo de cambiar el límite de amplitud en autorrespondidas es un muy buen punto. De hecho, creo que (implícitamente) siempre se tuvo en cuenta (ejemplo, una pregunta mía, a la que aportaste una muy buena respuesta, que podría haber sido cerrada si no era ese el formato). Pero creo que en esta en cuestión hay un problema: está planteada de una forma que nadie más puede responder, y eso es lo que yo no acepto. Es una pregunta que básicamente dice "cuál es la mejor forma de hacer lo que voy a responder". ¿Fomentar aportes aceptando la verdad de uno sólo? No me gusta.

Comment: @Mariano ¿Por qué no puede responder nadie más? Cuando se cierran es cuando no puede responder nadie más. Si la autorespuesta es tan buena que nadie pone una respuesta mejor perfecto, es lo que queremos, respuestas buenas. Si hay quien tiene una respuesta mejor la puede poner.

Comment: Jamás dudé de la excelente calidad de la respuesta, y es un contenido que me gustaría que esté incluído en el sitio (pero no la pregunta). En mi opinión, nadie más puede responder porque "*quisiera tener un punto de referencia que abarque los aspectos más importantes de PDO*" no es una pregunta concreta. Creo que le falta definir el contexto, el problema y el alcance.