# ¡Por favor, no conviertan SOes en un blog, foro...!

Tags: discusión

Últimamente he podido observar que quieren convertir SOes (*con fuerza mayor*), en un blog, foro o peor aún en una enciclopedia de programación.

¿En serio señoras y señores?

Por ejemplo, yo como programador (*en la vida real*), no me interesa en absoluto leer esto en SOes:

- Si han actualizado una librería y cuales son las nuevas características del mismo.
- Traducciones del inglés al español `1:1`, copias idénticas, referencias de otros blogs, foros..., con el contexto: ¿Que es? - ¿Para que sirven? - ¿Y como se implementa?

Si entro **YO** en SOes es para:

1. **Resolver problemas**, que pueden tener algunos en **un problema** en **concreto**.
2. Que me resuelvan **un problema** en **concreto**.

---

SOes es una herramienta para programadores y espero que siga ese camino, porque si no tendré un futuro bastante duro...

Comment: Jaja si, durisimo.. ahora si lleva mas de 3 minutos de leer, este no es el mejor formato, de acuerdo con eso. Pero ¿cual es el problema?.... no estoy seguro si estas rtas lo hacen, pero si algo aporta SEO, le sirve al sitio. por ahora, les doy una oportunidad (confieso que no las quiero leer y me molestan por eso)

Comment: Pensé que era el único que pensaba esto, es todo lo que pedimos a gritos los que intentamos responder preguntas y problemas puntuales, pero luego nos dicen que estamos atacando las buenas obras y empobreciendo la comunidad.

Comment: Lo de blog o foro entiendo de dónde viene. Pero no lo de foro, ¿puedes poner algún ejemplo de alguien que quiere hacer de SO un foro? Esta pregunta es un tema importante a debatir por lo que le doy +1, independientemente de que no esté de acuerdo la postura concreta.

Comment: No estoy al tanto de lo que quieren hacer, pero mi opinion es que StackOverflow en español debe ser lo mismo que StackOverfloe en ingles (pero en español), es decir, un sitio en donde gente de habla hispana puede preguntar y responder dudas tecnicas de programacion, estaria totalmente en desacuerdo que esto se transforme en un Blog.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Incluso estando muy de acuerdo contigo, hay que tener un poco de paciencia. La graduación se ha producido hace muy poco, y el número de revisores es todavía bastante pequeño, con lo que hay ciertas preguntas que pueden escaparse a la moderación.

Además, hay contenido con el que (en mi opinión) es posible que debamos ser relativamente *permisivos* todavía, contenido que por ejemplo en SOen se produjo al principio y que ahora no se admitiría, pero que da cabida a ciertas preguntas que aunque tal vez sean demasiado amplias para el formato de SO, permite poder enlazar un buen numero de preguntas habituales a estas respuestas como duplicados.

Dicho esto, yo tampoco quiero un SOes convertido en un blog/foro técnico. Hace poco @A.Cedano (en algunos comentarios que ahora no encuentro) expresaba la falta de este tipo de recursos en español, con lo que puedo estar de acuerdo. Pero creo que SOes **no es el sitio ideal para ello** dado su formato de preguntas/respuestas. Otra cosa es plantearnos si sería interesante crear algun sitio tipo [Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/) (pero bien hecho, porque en mi opinion el formato tampoco es bueno). Pero no aqui.

---

Aclaración: Yo estoy totalmente a favor de respuestas canónicas, como por ejemplo (modestamente pongo dos mias):

[NullReferenceException: ¿Qué es y cómo puedo solucionarla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/76861/15301)

[¿Qué es una NullReferenceException y cómo solucionarla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75999/15301)

Para mi el problema son las preguntas inconcretas o excesivamente amplias, no que una pregunta totalmente aceptable (*este código me lanza una excepción x*) de lugar a una respuesta extensa que responda a cualquier pregunta que sea idéntica aunque el código que lo provoque sea diferente.

Comment: No es cuestión de paciencia...(Yo tengo de sobra) Pero si tienes a un hermano grande (SO)... el sitio SOes se ha graduado... porque se sigue intentando de convertir esto en lo dicho? Estoy muy de acuerdo de hacer un Documentation... pero mientras tanto (y por favor) no admitir estos `pseudo documentation`

Comment: Como ya he dicho yo estoy bastante de acuerdo contigo. Pero de todas maneras no considero que se esté siendo excesivamente permisivo con ese tipo de preguntas/respuestas, de hecho meta está repleto de quejas precisamente en el sentido contrario. Lo cual demuestra que al menos de momento, la mayoría de usuarios de la comunidad van en la misma línea. Lo cual no impide que otras personas tengan una idea diferente, y traten de que se imponga. Estan en todo su derecho de hacerlo

Comment: Esta todo correcto en lo que dices... Y precisamente por eso he publicado esta `petición`.. porque hay (últimamente al mi parecer) muchas quejas en Meta y también por haber leído algunos comentarios que dan hasta miedo...

Comment: @aldanux por el bien del debate y así fijar el alcance, ¿podrías referenciar esos comentarios en la pregunta?

Comment: @fedorqui - claro que podría... pero ahora mismo no tengo el tiempo suficiente para redactar/buscar esos comentarios... además no pretendo de acusar a nadie.. es una petición en general...

Comment: @aldanux no, no, si no es cuestión de acusar. Cada cual utiliza SOes de una manera y es legítimo exponerlas para contrastar. [_¡Luz, más luz!_](http://medicablogs.diariomedico.com/laboratorio/2014/07/30/luz-mas-luz/)

Comment: Aclaro que mi intención no es convertir esSO en un foro. Pero no veo por qué no puede existir cierto tipo de contenido que sirva de orientación en cosas que son repetitivas, pienso por ejemplo en el eterno problema de las consultas SQL mal escritas, el uso inadecuado de herramientas como PDO de PHP. Hace poco hubo un intento de mi parte en ese sentido: tener una pregunta-respuesta que sirva de referencia para evitar tener que estar repitiendo lo mismo hasta el infinito... y las respuestas de muchos de nosotros que inducen a error, manteniendo código vulnerable.

Comment: @A.Cedano - 1. No puedes y es imposible de contestar en una respuesta a todas las preguntas de SOes 2. Cada pregunta debería ser individual 3. Si no es individual es porque existe ya una pregunta con posibles respuestas.... es lo que se llama aquí `duplicado` o quizás relacionado y por ultimo... para tener esa guía... como dice también Pikoh no es el sitio adecuado...  hay cientos (quizás exagero) de blogs y foros donde se puede informar el uso correcto de la librería o lo que sea... cual se puede indicar como un plus en la respuesta...

Comment: Nota aparte: Es una impresión mía personal como recibo yo, que quieren cambiar SOes (en general) y no es mi intención de atacar o acusar aquí a nadie personal... por eso no menciono ningún comentario o post porque no es relevante... Saludos a todos

Comment: Entiendo tu planteamiento @aldanux, pero, toma en cuenta lo que comento en mi respuesta. Tener cierto contenido bien elaborado podría ayudar a que **no** se siga perpetuando _código obsoleto_. Desde mi experiencia te puedo decir que desde esSO, si nos descuidamos, se podría ayudar a perpetuar código obsoleto, sobre todo cuando respondemos basándonos en el mismo código y la respuesta es marcada como solución. En ese caso, se trata sólo de una solución _ilusoria_, las consecuencias para el OP podrían ser terribles y esSO se convierte en una _pila_ de código pésimo que otros copiarán como bueno.

Comment: @A.Cedano lo que comentas respecto a código pésimo es relativo. Si un fragmento de código en una respuesta se vuelve obsoleto, entonces se publica una nueva respuesta con el código renovado, la comunidad votaría a favor y, aunque no sea la respuesta aceptada, será la más votada porque funciona. La comunidad en SOes en ese sentido es madura.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza _La comunidad en SOes en ese sentido es madura_ ¿Seguro? Como dije en mi respuesta, a veces he tenido que ser pesado o molesto con algunos usuarios de esSO bastante maduros que han respondido a preguntas sin indicar en ninguna parte que el código es obsoleto o inseguro. Casi todos, es cierto, han rectificado poniendo un comentario al respecto en sus respuestas. No creo que hayamos alcanzado todavía el nivel de madurez suficiente.

Comment: @A.Cedano que un usuario tenga más de 10k de reputación no significa que sea maduro, solo significa que sus publicaciones ayudan a muchas personas en el sitio. Pues a cualquier desarrollador, inclusive a los más experimentados (o que tengan muchos años de experiencia, pero no es una relación directa), se les puede escapar código obsoleto o inseguro (para mí si un usuario publica muchas respuestas tenga con código inseguro, menos confiaría en él o ella). Me refiero a que la comunidad es madura en reconocer las mejores opciones si se explican adecuamente.

Comment: Cuidado, canonico y _mas de 3 minutos en leer_ no son excluyentes, se puede tener ambas. El problema para mi, es que esas respuestas (20 minutos de lectura) no las voy a leer, casi bajo ninguna circunstancia y eso es malo para la respuesta, no para mi.

Answer (score 6):

```
Esto es Stack Overflow en español
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Hasta aquí todos de acuerdo imagino.
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Pero el problema es que si Harald hiciese hoy la anterior
pregunta en StackOverflow quizás sea esto lo que se encontraría:
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quien piense que exagero tiene aquí algunos ejemplos reales :

- [¿Qué es una función universal?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6279/qu%C3%A9-es-una-funci%C3%B3n-universal) Está bien claro lo que se pregunta para quien sepa qué es una función universal y no hace falta un libro para responder.
- [Como puedo conectar javascript con MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/14895/como-puedo-conectar-javascript-con-mysql) Si fuese en Java yo podría responder en una página, no conozco javascript pero dudo que cueste mucho más.
- [¿Para enviar una imagen a un webservices debo codificarla a Base64?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18296/para-enviar-una-imagen-a-un-webservices-debo-codificarla-a-base64) Marcar esto como demasiado amplio es... Esta pregunta se resuelve con un monosílabo. O mejor con un par de líneas explicando que no tiene por qué ser Base64 pero sí has de utilizar una codificación que no interfiera con el documento HTML en que se encapsula la imagen.

Son preguntas como las del recorrido. ¿Cómo evitar que los unicornios se coman las margaritas? ¿Cómo puedo conectar javascript con MySQL?

Pero no se aceptan, pese a ser el mismo estilo que el ejemplo del recorrido.
**Sufrimos en SOes de un deseo de algunos de restringirnos a preguntas muy concretas.**
En detrimento de otras algo más generales que sí son habituales en toda la red de Stack Exchange y aquí se quiere restringir. Esto sí es convertir SOes en lo que no es.

> Por ejemplo, yo como programador (en la vida real), no me interesa en
>   absoluto leer esto en SOes:
>
> - Si han actualizado una librería y cuales son las nuevas características del mismo.

Pues la mar de bien. No lo leas. Pero a otros sí nos interesa, sí forma parte de la temática del sítio y sí es relevante en las preguntas en que se trata esas librerías que han sido actualizadas.
Nosotros no te obligamos ni prohibimos nada. Por favor procura no prohibirnos el comentar cuando una respuesta utiliza versiones obsoletas o prácticas inseguras.

> - Traducciones del inglés al español 1:1, copias idénticas, referencias de otros blogs, foros..., con el contexto: ¿Que es? - ¿Para que sirven? - ¿Y como se implementa?

[Las traducciones sí se admiten.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/15/301) Otra vez lo mismo, si no te interesa no lo uses. Pero no pongas trabas a los que queremos contribuir en temas o formas que no te interesan. Nosotros no te las ponemos a ti.

Comment: hay muchas preguntas cerradas por gente que desconoce el lenguaje y le parece que la pregunta es inapropiada. Ya hice re abrir varias por esos motivos. Habia una pregunta en meta respecto de esto. Estoy de acuerdo con lo de las traducciones (generan trafico). Estoy de acuerdo con lo de comentar que existen nuevas funcionalidades, siempre y cuando no cambie el espiritu de lo que pregunta OP. Muchas veces se le dice a OP asi no se hace, instala la version XX y usa YY.. sin saber si quiera si Op tiene la capacidad para hacer eso.

Comment: En qué momento he dicho de prohibir? Estoy haciendo una petición que SOes no se convierta en un blog o similar...

Comment: @aldanux Sugieres a alguien que haga su pregunta/respuesta en un blog, por ejemplo [aquí](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2279/qu%c3%a9-ocurre-con-la-pregunta-manejar-conexiones-a-bases-de-datos-mysql-mediante/2287#comment7035_2279), y luego pides que no se permitan "blogs". Es legítimo hacerlo, pero no deja de ser pedir que se prohiban esas preguntas/respuestas a las que tu llamas blog.

Comment: Pues eso mismo... llama me anti-blogger...

Comment: @aldanux El problema es que llamas Blog a lo que no lo es. [Blog](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blog) es una abreviatura de Web Log;​ es un sitio web que incluye, a modo de diario personal de su autor o autores, contenidos de su interés, actualizados con frecuencia y a menudo comentados por los lectores. Usas la palabra Blog para desacreditar preguntas/respuestas que no son Blogs. Si no quieres esas preguntas/respuestas dilo de frente.

Comment: Sin problemas... no me gustan y no deberían estar esas preguntas / respuestas en todo SO... ahora mejor y mas claro? Corrige me si no es así...

Comment: Lo que veo en las dos primeras preguntas que pones como ejemplo es que una simple búsqueda en Google podría resolver el problema, y normalmente no somos (o no deberíamos) ser el sustituto de Google. Noto mucho rencor en tu respuesta hacia quienes según tú limitan (¿limitamos?) el uso de SO para preguntas sobre problemas puntuales de programación, creo que la comunidad no es madura aún (como comunidad, no me refiero a las personas) y todas estas discusiones forman parte de la evolución de SO, te invito entonces a dejar ese sentimiento a un lado y no tomarlo personal.

Comment: @Shaz ¿Qué texto has usado para buscar en Google qué es una función universal en Python? ¿Qué enlace te ha dado donde se explique?

Comment: Utilicé: "función universal" python.

Comment: @Shaz ¿Y cual de los resultados que aparecen consideras que explica bien qué es una función universal?

Answer (score -2):

En lo personal, considero que, si bien esSO no es ni un blog ni un foro, ello no impide que existan algunas preguntas-respuestas que sirvan como puntos de referencia.

Pienso en un caso concreto, basado en mi experiencia:

En el caso concreto de PHP (como podría ser el caso de cualquier lenguaje), la mayoría de código y tutoriales que existen son antiguos. En consecuencia, muchos programadores aprendices toman ese código y empiezan a elaborar sus programas. Cuando tienen un error o dificultad, lo plantean aquí en esSO, compartiendo ese código antiguo que han tomado del tutorial x, publicado, digamos en el año 2005.

De 2005 para acá ha llovido mucho...

El problema de código antiguo tiene para mí dos enfoques:

**1. El OP que pregunta compartiendo código antiguo:**

Yo veo constantemente en esSO preguntas con estas características. Un caso típico es el de PHP/MySQL. Si hacemos una revisión, veremos que una gran mayoría del código está basado, en el peor de los casos, en la extensión `mysql_*`, declarada obsoleta porque pone seriamente en riesgo los datos. Y muchas veces, si se usa la extensión recomendada por PHP actualmente (PDO o MySQLi), se usa mal, porque no se implementan consultas preparadas.

**2. Cualquiera de nosotros que responde a esa pregunta planteada con código antiguo**

Ante preguntas basadas en código obsoleto, vulnerable... he visto que muchos de nosotros responde (o respondía), *resolviendo* el problema. Es decir, haciendo que un código vulnerable funcione. A mi juicio, hacer eso, en vez de resolver un problema, lo que hace es crear uno más grave, ya que, cuando el código vulnerable funcione, cualquier usuario mal intencionado podrá sacar total provecho de él. Al menos si no funciona, el hacker no podrá hacer nada.

Yo he sido quizá *molesto* para algunos, indicándoles en comentarios a respuestas de ese tipo, que al menos indique al OP que su código es peligroso, mostrándole enlaces para que se actualice, pues algunos simplemente respondían aportando una *ilusoria* solución al problema. **Creo que en ese caso, *resolver* el problema no significa hacer funcionar ese código... porque el problema mayor es que el OP necesita actualizarse.**

Por otra parte, creo que hacer eso, ayuda a perpetuar código de ese tipo... haciendo que esSO sea algo así como un blog, un foro, o lo que sea, del año 2005. ¿Por qué? Porque si el OP marca como solución una respuesta basada en el mismo código que el planteó (obsoleto, vulnerable, peligroso), cuando alguien tenga el mismo problema y entre en esa pregunta, lo primero que buscará será la respuesta marcada como solución y tratará de resolver su problema en base a ese código. No sé si alcanzan ustedes a entender el enorme riesgo que eso supone. En ese caso, esSO, en vez de ser una ayuda para superarse, es una ayuda para seguir perpetuando código obsoleto.

En lo personal, cuando veo preguntas de ese tipo, hago un comentario al OP sobre la situación de su código y si se muestra dispuesto a implementar un código seguro, entonces procedo a responder usando código seguro y actualizado. Yo creo que, un programador que se respete, no debería **nunca** escribir en una respuesta un código que sea vulnerable, porque es posible que otros copien ese código y lo utilicen como *bueno* cuando no lo es en absoluto.

**En conclusión pienso que:**

esSO no es un blog, no es un foro... pero podría tener algunas preguntas-respuestas bien elaboradas, sobre todo en casos muy concretos que se repiten una y otra vez, que muestren la manera correcta de hacer las cosas.

Comment: Entiendo...pero no lo puedes generalizar... porque no sabes en que versión trabaja o si es un código viejo de un cliente y no quiere cambiar todo.... en fin existe un montón de causas porque se usa aún códigos obsoleta...¡ojo!  lo que no quiere decir que siempre sea menos seguro...es el programador que lo hace inseguro en mi opinion.... así que cuando se contesta a una código obsoleta se le puede indicar que esta andando en riesgo... y ya...

Comment: @aldanux Para eso existen los comentarios. Si en comentario el OP indica que es obligatorio mantener ese código, se podría aportar una solución, indicando de forma bien visible el peligro que ello supone. Pensando sobre todo en otros usuarios con el mismo problema que podrían en cambio usar extensiones actualizadas.

Comment: Yo lo indicaría en la mayoría o siempre... aunque el OP no haya avisado nada... es como lo haz dicho ya... si alguien en un futuro vea solo la respuesta al problema que tenga al menos bien claro... que puede andar en _peligro_...

Comment: Cuando uno pone codigo viejo, obsoleto, antiguo, inseguro.. es un peligro para quien?? y si uno lo hace conciente?? a veces solucionar problemas asumiendo riesgos esta bien... digo, si a cada uno que corrijo en .net le tengo que aclarar que su codigo es una porqueria, tendria que pasarme el dia aclarando esas cosas. No se puede solucionar el mundo desde atras de un monitor. Y no se puede saber que le pasa a los OP cada vez que preguntan. PHP no es el unico lenguaje. y todos son vulnerables de alguna forma.

Comment: @gbianchi tu comentario suena a _resignación_. Considero que esSO puede ser una herramienta excelente para ayudar a progresar a muchos usuarios en ese sentido, aunque resulte más cuesta arriba. El camino más corto no es siempre el mejor.

Comment: No es resignacion. Es un principio de programacion q se llama YAGNI. Si mi pagina es de una red interna, realmente necesito leer 600 pag de manual pq bo cumple con estandares o es insegura? Uno va agregando standares a medida q necesita.. tirarle medio libro a un op q pregunto por una consulta php, cuando solo necesitaba arreglarla, para mi pto de vista no ayuda. No se q otros sitios de la red usas, pero cuando voy a otro sitio a preguntar algo, espero la respuesta puntual, no un manual de uso.

Comment: @gbianchi creo que no has entendido del todo mi punto de vista. No sé si no me he explicado bien en la respuesta. En ningún momento he dicho que haya que soltarle un manual al OP en cada respuesta. He dicho que es necesario indicarle sobre la obsolescencia y posible peligrosidad de su código, proponerle de actualizarlo y por otra parte, he dicho que no veo por qué no tener algunas buenas respuestas que sirvan como punto de referencia en casos muy repetitivos, los cuales existen, como habrás podido ver. Yo no cpncibo esSO como una _pila_ de código mal escrito, y ¡puede acabar siendo eso!.

Comment: @A.Cedano - Si usas por ejemplo el [IDE PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/)... puedes configurar en que versión de `PHP` trabajas y te avisa automáticamente cual de las funciones son obsoletas o no permitidas... (no se de otros IDE si te avisan también) es solo una info el comentario...

Answer (score -2):

Perdónenme, no llevo mucho tiempo en esta pagina, pero cada vez que veo una pregunta veo que casi nadie brinda respuestas y cuando la brindan (en lugar de responder) dicen cosas como

- "tu pregunta esta mal formulada"
- "copia y pega tu código"
- "copia y pega mas código"
- o preguntan cosas que no están relacionadas con la respuesta (intuyo que quieren ayudar pero no saben)

Entonces pregunto: ¿Que tiene de malo que alguien quiera copiar y pegar código en situaciones donde casi nadie se digna a responder?

En mi experiencia particular me ha tocado auto-responderme varias de mis preguntas por que no he conseguido que me brinden una respuesta/solución (aun en preguntas que llevan dias/semanas), en la mayoría de los casos ni siquiera tengo respuestas, solo visitas.

Y a eso sumemosle:

- Los que te editan la pregunta 30 veces (pero no escriben comentarios/respuestas)
- Los justicieros anónimos que te llenan los comentarios de votos negativos por que les caíste mal.

Esta pagina debería ser mas inclusiva, abrirse mas al cambio, a las necesidades de los usuarios que quizás hoy no se estén satisfaciendo en ninguno otro lado.

Por otro lado, eso de las preguntas de cambios de versión y etc, apoyo lo que decís, no es lo ideal, pero en todo caso podría ponerse en una sección especial y que si en todo caso no quieras ver ese tipo de preguntas, tildes o destiles un checkbox y listo, chau problema.

Comment: Me parece que sólo estás viendo las preguntas recién publicadas. ¿Es así?

Comment: Hola Ruben, te planteo un caso puntual: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/84449/como-generar-archivos-excel-en-base-a-un-template-con-interacci%C3%B3n-de-usuario

Comment: Esta pregunta la hice hace 10 días, nadie la respondió pero recibí 24 visitas. Hoy me dispuse a cerrar la pregunta con una respuesta propia y a los 10 minutos recibo una calificación negativa de algún justiciero anónimo. A eso me refiero.

Comment: Gracias por el enlace. En un momento lo veo. Cabe hacer notar que esta respuesta no responde a la pregunta. Hay otras preguntas similares a lo que planteas en tu respuesta, revísalas y si no encuentras ninguna que se ajuste a lo que quieres comunicar publica una nueva.

Comment: Y así tengo fácil 10 casos similares, pregunto algo, nadie responde, termino cerrando mi propia pregunta. Si ruben, la respuesta no brinda solución a la pregunta que hice, pero fue lo que mas se acercaba (digamos que cerre mi pregunta para no dejarla abierta mas que por la respuesta en si), y déjame decirte que googlie 100 sitios, incluyendo stackoverflow antes de hacer mi pregunta. Y ojo, veo que a muchos les pasa, veo muchas publicaciones sin responder o con respuestas que divagan en comentarios como "publica mas codigo" o "tu pregunta no se entiende"

Comment: Date cuenta que estas haciendo exactamente lo mismo que estoy mencionando: editas una pregunta, corregís algo y bye. Creo que lo mas importante en una pregunta es brindar una respuesta, no corregir la pregunta/corregir la respuesta. Sostengo lo que dije en un principio: en esta comunidad se brindan pocas respuestas pero si muchas criticas, como por ejemplo el que hizo este post.

Comment: Esta "página" como tu le llamas, no es como las demás. Tiene un "modelo peculiar" con el que aparentemente aún no estás familiarizado. En lo personal me parece que vale la pena conocer el modelo. Uno de sus elementos es que prácticamente no hay barreras para publicar preguntas y respuestas. Me parece a la mayoría toma algo de tiempo conocer y un poco más en sentirse cómodo con el mismo, en particular por cuando al empezar se reciben votos negativos. No los tomes a mal, son forma de darte retroalimentación.

Comment: El fin justifica los medios. La finalidad es que el que pregunta aprenda y/o tenga una respuesta que lo ayude a crecer en el conocimiento que esta necesitando. Si poner un link lo ayuda, bienvenido sea. Por contra parte, si estas haciendo un comentario por el simple hecho de que no te gusto X forma de realizarlo, eso es injustificado por que no hay ninguna finalidad detrás. Y sino volvamos a lo mismo: la pregunta estuvo 10 días abierta y nadie la respondió, y así hay cientos de casos. Para mi tienen los conceptos errados, no ayudan a nadie criticando en exceso.

Comment: Como ya te había mencionado antes, esta respuesta no responde la pregunta. Si en realidad te interesa que lo que aquí expones tenga la atención debida, primero busca una pregunta que trate el tema de inconformidad con el modelo, trato a nuevos usuarios, o el que consideres más apropiado, y si no la encuentras publica una nueva pregunta.

Comment: Tu opinión es importante y valiosa. Hay que considerar que existen formas para formular las preguntas (revisar [ask]) y las respuestas (revisar [answer]), tanto en SOes como en Meta. Te sugiero que, para este caso, sería mejor publicar una nueva pregunta explicando tus inquietudes y que la comunidad pueda ayudarte al respecto. Allí recibirá más atención de lo esperado.