# Reemplacemos el enlace a "A Theory of Moderation" por el de "Una teoría de moderación" en la página Revisar

Tags: característica-nueva, traducciones

En [Revisar del sitio principal](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review) y [Revisar de Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/review) (requiren de +500 de reputación<sup>[1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues)</sup>) se muestra el recuadro con título "Ayuda a mejorar el sitio"<sup>2</sup> en el cual se incluye el enlace a [A Theory of Moderation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/) el cual fue [traducido y publicado](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2227/65) en Meta recientemente.

Si esto procede, solicito también convertir la traducción a Wiki de Comunidad.

---

<sup>2</sup>: Ayuda a mejorar el sitio

[image: Ayuda a mejorar el sitio]

Comment: Lo tricundo :D Ya comentado antes en [¿Qué textos hay que no han sido traducidos?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2233/83)

Comment: @Mariano siendo estrictos, no se trata de una traducción sino de cambiar un par de enlaces, pero está bien si prefieren que quede como duplicado de aquel, no hay problema.

Comment: Es cierto, tenés razón... personalmente, estos casos donde se modifica un enlace en inglés por uno en español prefiero considerarlos junto a las traducciones, y así tener un panorama global de todas las traducciones  en una única publicación.

Comment: @Mariano Pienso que se debería actualizar "la pregunta" en cuestión para incluir en su alcance los enlaces a material traducido... mas tarde lo podría hacer yo mismo.

Comment: ¿Y no se podría agregar más texto al _anchor_? Por ejemplo que en lugar de _ti_, fuera __*es moderado por ti*__. Es que el ti, como que no se ve.

Comment: @toledano Qué gracia, pensé lo mismo y así lo puse en mi respuesta en el duplicado. Ese _ti_ es minúsculo.