# ¿Stack Overflow en español es legible?

Tags: discusión, preguntas

Un saludo. Soy muy nuevo en Stackoverflow, apenas empiezo a programar, y quizá ni siquiera debiera escribir esto, pero creo que tengo el derecho de hacerlo.

Hace unos días publiqué una pregunta: [Manejo de archivos en C++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/344922/manejo-de-archivos-en-c). Pues bien, después de la primera respuesta, como seguía sin ser capaz de resolver el problema, decidí que era buena idea responder añadiendo el código y nuevos detalles **fruto de las modificaciones llevadas a cabo a raíz de esa respuesta**. Ni de broma se podía eso hacer en un comentario. Ni un minuto tardó un moderador -con todo el respeto- en decirme que eliminara la respuesta, que no podía responder a mi propia pregunta para añadir información.

Para empezar, yo no estaba añadiendo información, sino informando del resultado obtenido tras hacer lo sugerido en la respuesta, y por tanto me parece lógico que esté a continuación de la respuesta. Pero no, tuve que ponerlo en un *edit* del post original. Ahora pongámonos en la piel de alguien que simplemente llega al hilo buscando en *Google* un problema igual o similar. ¿De verdad va a entender bien el post, habiendo en él información que ni siquiera viene a cuento sin haber leído previamente la respuesta a raíz de la cual se obtiene esa nueva información?

A mi no me parece mal que se quiera que esto sea un sitio muy formal, de *preguntas y respuestas*, pero quizá fuera más conveniente que se pareciese un poco más a un foro, y que se pueda leer de forma secuencial sin tener que estar buscando dónde está cada cosa. Probablemente a los que estáis acostumbrados no os cuesta nada, pero no creo que sea el sistema más eficiente.

Lo dicho, solo he querido dejar mi opinión sobre el tema, siempre con el máximo respeto y con intención totalmente constructiva.

Un saludo.

Comment: Siempre puedes añadir el contexto de lo que habías intentado (en base a una respuesta que probablemente luego sería modificada o eliminada) en el OP...

Comment: Sigue siendo liar el hilo. Con lo sencillo y legible para todo el mundo que es el sistema pregunta- respuesta.

Comment: @Intento_de_programador *Con lo sencillo y legible para todo el mundo que es el sistema pregunta- respuesta*. Precisamente los que intentamos es mantener el sistema: hay una pregunta y una o varias respuestas independientes entre sí. Las respuestas son soluciones al problema expuesto, no parte del diálogo que se hace con comentarios

Comment: Agregando a lo que dice pablo, cuando los comentarios se hacen muy largos, solemos borrarlos....

Comment: Ah, y ojo. La votacion en meta es diferente al sitio principal.. aca se puntua el acuerdo o desacuerdo con la publicacion, no si esta correcta o incorrecta la misma...

Comment: Y te comentaria otra cosa.. ese sistema que vos decis que es ineficiente... lleva mas de 10 años vivo.. y una red de mas de 100 sitios...

Answer (score 8):

Justamente, esto no es un foro. Es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas.

Quien te comento no fue un moderador, fue otro usuario comun y corriente. Los moderadores tenemos un diamante al lado de nuestro nombre, pero no por eso somos diferentes al resto. Solo estamos para las situaciones especiales.

En tu caso, tu pregunta estaba bien planteada, y las observaciones fueron correctas...

Las respuestas son respuestas..

Llegado el caso, podias abrir una nueva pregunta referenciando la pregunta anterior.

Y una de las principales diferencias de este sitio, es la facilidad para cualquiera, no solamente vos, de buscar soluciones a problemas comunes. Y si no esta en este formato que usamos, es dificil de encontrar una respuesta.

Y otro de los puntos importantes, es que todos moderamos el sitio, vos tambien.

Comment: Ohhhh :'( justo en mi corazón con esa frase de *común y corriente*

Comment: @BetaM salvando las distancia por el poder que me dieron, somos todos usuarios comunes y corrientes...

Comment: Efectivamente como página es excelente, precisamente por la capacidad de moderación de todo el mundo, idea que me parece muy buena. Lo que no me gusta es eso, tanto "sube y baja" que hay que hacer para poder realmente llegar a la solución e -importante- entender de dónde viene. Personalmente creo inútil copiar y pegar código sin saber qué hace solo porque hay al lado un *check* verde. Eso no es programar.

Comment: @Intento_de_programador no entiendo lo del sube y baja. Por eso se pide que las respuestas sean claras y completas... La de paper (como todas las de el) es maravillosa... si a vos no te funciono por algo en particular, tal vez tu problema este en otro lado. Tal vez un pequeño ejemplo hubiera solucionado el problema. un programa que solo haga eso, para comprobar donde estaba el problema.

Comment: El problema creo que va a ser (aún no lo he probado) el tipo de objeto creado. PaperBirdMaster da una ayuda inmejorable y yo de él no me quejo en absoluto. Incluso agradezco sus críticas a mi trabajo aunque excedan el ámbito de la pregunta. Y espero que pronto pueda yo empezar a ayudar también aquí, y no solo a preguntar.

Comment: @Intento_de_programador por supuesto que si!! todos empezamos de cero en algun lado.. y muchos nos consideramos novatos eternos...

Comment: Perdón, pero tengo entendido que los moderadores somos los que tenemos privilegios de moderación. Ref. [Una teoría de modeación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2227/65).

Answer (score 5):

Yo te hice las observaciones para que eliminaras el contenido que no era respuesta y lo colocaras como edición a tu pregunta.

Dicho lo anterior analizemos algunos puntos:

- La plataforma te permite preguntar y que una o varias personas expongan una *posible solución* donde tu marcarás como aceptada y/o votarás positivo la que mejor se adapte a tu problema
- La zona de respuestas *que se encuentra debajo* de la pregunta es solo para eso, exponer posibles soluciones
- Para hacerle preguntas, aclaraciones o pedir mejoras a la respuesta puedes usar la *zona de comentarios*
- Tu pregunta puede ser editada en cualquier momento, lo cual de hecho es bueno pues te permite agregar o quiar información en función de mejorar su calidad y facilidad de comprensión de la misma.

A lo que originalmente respondiste, yo te pregunté:

**¿esto es una respuesta a tu pregunta?**

De lo que se obtuvo que no y que era un comentario para PaperBirdMaster para darle a conocer nueva información.

Comentas:

> Para empezar, yo no estaba añadiendo información, sino informando del resultado obtenido tras hacer lo sugerido en la respuesta, y por tanto me parece lógico que esté a continuación de la respuesta.

Bueno dicierno de lo mencionado y expongo el por que:

> Si un usuario entra y lee una pregunta principal, luego una respuesta, luego una respuesta (que en realidad es un comentario con aclaraciones a la respuesta 1), luego lee una respuesta (dirigida a la *no respuesta no. 2*) y así sucesivamente....

- ¿Cómo sabe cuál es la solución?
- ¿Cómo distinguirá el contexto completo de la pregunta, si esta se encuentra fragmentada en diversas *no respuestas*?
- La publicación parecerá una larga conversación de la cual los que no hayamos estado en ese momento no sabremos seguir *el hilo* de la misma

**Pero, yo tengo mas información que agregar mas dudas**

Si lo anterior fuera el caso dispones de:

- Ediciones a la pregunta
- Zona de comentarios
- Incluso acceder al chat donde puedes abrir una sala para discutir todo lo referente a tu pregunta con el usuario o usuarios que te respondieron

En resumen:

Las ediciones a tu pregunta no la desmehjoran ni la hacen difícil de comprender, al contrario servirá y de mucho a futuros usuarios dado que observarán:

- Pregunta completa con código
- Contexto amplio y completo donde leerán todo lo realizado
- Una única respuesta o varias atendiendo a solucionar una pregunta amplia y bien fundamentada y explicada
- Evitarán perderse *en un mar* de posts donde no se sabe si la solución esta en 1 o varios de ellos

Al final te diría:

¿Tu serías capaz de comprender una publicación llena de preguntas/respuestas donde no se sabe donde parte y termina la solución?

¿no sería mas simple una pregunta bien enfocada y varias respuestas donde la mas completa sea la aceptada y nos de *luz* de la solución?

Comment: He participado en muchísimos sitios de soporte, en programación todavía voy cojo, pero haciendo malabares con los ordenadores llevo bastante. Durante un tiempo fui muy activo en la comunidad de Linux Mint, donde excelentes usuarios resolvían y resuelven problemas, muchos de ellos MUY complejos, y se sigue un patrón de foro normal. Nada de eso hace que te pierdas, al revés. Ando también por los foros de HP, ForoSpyware... Existen las citas, las respuestas a otros comentarios que se marcan como tal, y en general mecanismos que no te hacen ir de Sevilla a Cáceres por Barcelona...

Comment: Que te digo... tienes ya 2 respuesta, eso se volvería cuestión de opiniones; la red de SE se soporta en esta dinámica amigo

Comment: Me parece perfecto, voy a seguir usando SO y espero que se me siga tratando tan bien como hasta ahora. Solo era una opinión humilde y nada más ;) Sigue siendo la mejor web de consultas de programación, eso no os lo quita nadie, pero creo que nunca está mal poder expresarse, siempre que no se ofenda a nadie (ofender... cosa muy de moda aquí en España últimamente, pero eso lo dejo para StackPolítica :) )